# Filter through class string properties

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I'd like to filter through class `User` string-properties in any order.

My `User` class looks like this:

```
internal class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string Email { get; }

    public User(string firstName, string lastName, string email)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Email = email;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{FirstName} {LastName} - {Email}";
    }
}
```

And my Filter algorithm looks like this:

```
    private readonly List<User> _userList = new List<User>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _userList.Add(new User("Zar", "Nikolaus II", "ruler@stackoverflow.bom"));
        _userList.Add(new User("Tommy", "Hilfiger", "polo@stackoverflow.bom"));
        _userList.Add(new User("Nina", "Richy", "thin-thing@stackoverflow.bom"));
        _userList.Add(new User("Armin", "Van Buren", "singer@stackoverflow.bom"));
        _userList.Add(new User("Lauren", "Ralph", "polo@stackoverflow.bom"));
        _userList.Add(new User("Van der Vaart", "(Marin-) Rafael", "soccer@stackoverflow.bom"));
        _userList.Add(new User("Tommy", "Vercetti", "character@stackoverflow.bom"));
    }

    private void FilterIt()
    {
        var filter = textBox1.Text;
        var properties = typeof(User).GetProperties();
        var filteredUsers = this._userList.Where(user => properties.Any(propInfo => Regex.Split(propInfo.GetValue(user).ToString(), @"\W").Any(w => filter.Contains(w))));
    }
```

Now my goal is get following results with the following filter:

**Filter: Tom**

1. **Tom**my Hilfiger - polo@stackoverflow.bom
2. **Tom**my Vercetti - character@stackoverflow.bom

**Filter: van**

1. **Van** der Vaart (Marin-) Rafael - soccer@stackoverflow.bom
2. Armin **Van** Buren - singer@stackoverflow.bom

**Filter: rafa va**

1. **Va**n der **Va**art (Marin-) **Rafa**el - soccer@stackoverflow.bom
2. Armin **Va**n Buren - singer@stackoverflow.bom

**Filter: ra**

1. Lauren **Ra**lph - polo@stackoverflow.bom
2. Van der Vaart (Marin-) **Ra**fael - soccer@stackoverflow.bom
3. Tommy Vercetti - cha**ra**cter@stackoverflow.bom

Comment: Okay, so where are you having problems? I would first separate out the "doing things with reflection" from "matching strings with regular expressions" aspects. They're orthogonal, and your SO question should be about *one* of those, and only one. (In both cases, a [mcve] would be useful - no UI is required.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only trick is to put `ToString()` - `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email` combination when matching:

```
string filter = "rafa va";

// We assume that 
//   1. Patterns are separated by space (or tabulation)
//   2. Patterns should be matched in any order 
//   3. Case should be ignored 
var patterns = filter
  .Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(item => Regex.Escape(item)) // <- comment it out if you want to allow, say, \d+ 
  .ToArray();

var result = _userList
  .Where(user => patterns
     .All(pattern => Regex.IsMatch(user.ToString(), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));
```